# Creating very simple cronjob in VScode to execute scraper.py

Tags: python-3.x, cron

i am trying to learn how to create a cronjob, but there are so many ways to do so...
It seems none is working for me.

I have a file named Cron.py:

```
from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab()
my_cron= CronTab(user='ttmz')
job = my_cron.new(command='python beddenscraper.py')
job.minute.every(1)

cron.write()
```

and that should trigger beddenscraper.py:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

scraped_data=[]
details= {}


page=requests.get('https://www.swisssense.nl/bedden')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

products = soup.find_all("a", class_="product-item-link")
prices = soup.find_all("span", class_="price")
images = soup.find_all("img", class_="product-image-photo")



bed_data = soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class", "item product product-item"})# total number of bedden

for bed in bed_data:
    bed_naam = bed.find("a", class_="product-item-link").getText()
    bed_price = bed.find(
        "span", class_="price"
    ).getText()  # print(bed_naam.text, bed_price.text)
    scraped_data.append(
        {"bed_naam": bed_naam.strip(), "bed_price": bed_price.strip()}
    )

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(scraped_data)
dataFrame.to_csv('swisssense.csv', index=False)
```

so: unfortunatly i get a ton of error messages.
Also some are using Crontab-e in terminal, or crontab -1.. none work for me so i think im doing something really wrong. Cant really find anything to explain on the web.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your program needs to work. I did not look it. Hopefully, it does work. However, instead of trying to make it work AND get crontab right AND getting the Python crontab entry program right, do those one at a time.

1. I tried the [python-crontab demo](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/), which simply evaluates the bash statement `echo hello_world`. I changed the user from `root` to `mslinn`. You should start with this also, using the appropriate user id.

```sh
$ pip install python-crontab 

$ python <<EOF
> from crontab import CronTab
> cron = CronTab(user='mslinn')
> job = cron.new(command='echo hello_world')
> job.minute.every(1)
> cron.write()
> EOF

$ crontab -l | tail -n 1
* * * * * echo hello_world
```

`crontab -l`  shows that the proper entry was made in user `mslinn`'s crontab.

2. Because crontab does not run in an interactive shell, output is not visible in your shell. I recommend your program write output to a file. If you insist on sending output to STDOUT or STDERR, you can email crontab output (but all the crontab entries will have their output emailed!) To email output, put this at the top of the crontab: `MAILTO=email@example.com`, [as per the docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab).
3. Test your program from the command line.
4. Only now try running your program from crontab.